# Using chi-squared or binomial for triangle test of discrimination

Tags: chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution, discriminant-analysis

Regarding beer taste testing. The wonderful people at Brulosophy do many experiments with beer, changing brew and fermentation methods and then using triangle tests to see whether there's a difference. The literature on sensory discrimination mentions use of both the chi square and binomial methods. E.g. http://www.academia.edu/29537820/Discrimination_Testing
I can't glean any notion of when it's appropriate to use one or the other.

Can you give me some pointers?

Cheers!

Comment: Please describe your 'triangle taste test'. (_One_ type I've encountered is that each person tests 2 of previous and 1 of new and tries to pick the new--just to _identify_ not to express preference.) What info on each subject? How many subjects? Only one new variation in your data?

Comment: Two products - A and B. Participants are given three samples consisting of either two A and one of B or vice versa, and have to identify the odd-one-out. There are six combinations of A and B order (ABB, AAB, ABA, BAA, BBA, BAB), and ideally you distribute those orders evenly across subjects. Subject reports '1','2', or '3' as being different, giving 1/3 probability of guessing correct. This is purely to identify the odd-one, not to express preference. Participant numbers are usually above 20, below 50.

Answer (score 2):

I assume each subject is given three samples of beer to taste, two of them
made according to the current recipe and one according to the new recipe. The subject tries to identify the one that tastes different from the other two.

Your null hypothesis is that the new recipe does not taste different.
Suppose $n$ subjects taste independently in this way, and $X$ of of them
make a correct identification. Then under the null hypothesis
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n, 1/3).$

If there are $n = 10$ tasters and $X = 8$ of them make correct identifications, then the
P-value of the test is $P(X \ge 8) = 0.0034 < 0.01$ and you have good evidence
to reject the null hypothesis at the 1% level, concluding that the new recipe tastes different.
(Computation in R statistical software.)

```
sum(dbinom(8:10, 10, 1/3))
[1] 0.003403953
```

This is an example of an exact binomial test. For larger $n,$ you might
use a normal approximation to the binomial distribution to find the P-value. 
In a more complex design you might use a chi-squared approximation.

*Notes:* (1) Experience in food and beverage industries has shown that it is best to
use professional tasters for such tests, especially if $n$ has to be small.
Randomly chosen 'beer lovers' may vary greatly in their tasting ability, some
unable to make distinctions immediately under test conditions that may prove to be
important over the long run. (2) If beer samples differ in appearance (color, clarity, etc.) and taste is *the* important issue, then it may be necessary to blindfold subjects or to serve samples
in opaque mugs under dim lighting.

Comment: Thanks for the code! I've not read all the Brulosophy posts, but that does indeed seem to be how they progress - first identify the good tasters (those that *can* discern a difference) with the triangle test, and then probe those individuals for preferences. I'm still uncertain as to why triangle tests can be evaluated with chi-squared and binomial methods - or really, what the differences are. Doing so yields quite substantially different p-values. A triangle-test really only has *one* design - in what way could it be more complex and hence appropriate to use chi-squared?

Comment: According to your description of the test and the numbers of subjects 20-50 used, I think exact binomial computations are the best way to get a P-value. If you feel comfortable using R, computations are as follows: For 20 subjects you would reject $H_0$ at the 5% level upon 11 or more correct identifications: the P-value for 12 correct IDs would be computed as `sum(dbinom(12:20, 20, 1/3))` which returns P-value  0.0129733. With 30 subj, 15 correct IDs gives P-value 0.043: `sum(dbinom(15:30, 30, 1/3))` returns 0.04348228. With these 2 examples plus the 1 in my Answer, you can see a pattern.

Comment: Thanks, BruceET, that's great. I think even if I weren't comfortable with R, the code provided would be perfectly intelligible.